# non-generic type IQueryable cannot be used with type argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating a task to retrieve data and I have an error when it gives two parameters to IQueryable

```
 public async Task<IQueryable<int, string>> ReasonForTheTecruitmentOrder(string type)
        {
            return _context.Dictionaries
                .Where(f => f.Type == type)
                .Select( f => new { f.Description, f.Id})
                .Distinct()
                ;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` has only one type parameter and you are actually returning anonymous objects, if you'll change return type to be `Task<IQueryable<object>>` this should work, although it won't be very helpful to have `object` generic type.

Comment: An anonymous object result can't be used by the caller. Try `f => (f.Description, f.Id)` instead, which creates a tuple, and then you can use `Task<IEnumerable<(string Description, int Id)>>`. (Using `IQueryable` outside query providers is rarely meaningful or needed.) Alternatively, declare a `record` with these fields and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use anonymous objects with IQueryable like this unless you use [generics](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics)

But here's a simpler solution that may help you:
First, create a class

```
public class KeyValuePairs
{
    public int Key {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

Next, use your method to return what you need:

```
public IQueryable<KeyValuePairs> ReasonForTheTecruitmentOrder(string type)
    {
        return _context.Dictionaries
            .Where(f => f.Type == type)
            .Select( f => new KeyValuePairs { Value = f.Description, Key = f.Id})
            .Distinct()
            ;
    }
```

I removed the asynchronous since there isn't an awaiter.